# Maritime version of "aviation"

Tags: nouns, phrase-requests

Is there an English noun that encompasses maritime activities in the way that *aviation* encompasses aeronautical activities?

[edit]

The accepted answer (seafaring) below fits my needs perfectly but I had an afterthought that I ought to give an example of expected usage, so-

example:

> "I would like to me other people who have an interest in ________"

Comment: The  Navy......?

Comment: Among single words, perhaps 'shipping' comes close, in the widest of its senses. But 'maritime activities' is what I'd stivk with.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth According to [this analysis](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Proportion-of-fleet-affected-by-four-noise-reduction-strategies-The-height-of-each_fig2_332241401)  , 'shipping' accounts for appx. 70% of maritime activities as classified by noise...so it is not an umbrella term for all ocean-going activity.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think 'shipping' normally refers to commercial seafaring, especially the movement of cargo. I was looking for a more general term to cover all types of maritime activities.

Comment: Usually when trying to meet people of similar interest you specify a little more:   Sailing, boating, yachting, submarining etc.

Comment: You could say, “... an interest in all things nautical.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***seafaring***

> (mass noun) The practice of regularly traveling by sea.

‘Canadian ***seafaring*** is a fraction of what it once was’

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/seafaring)

...and from [Merriam_Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seafaring)

> (noun) **the use of the sea for travel or transportation**

"On islands spanning from the Taiwan Strait to Polynesia live the Austronesians, best known for their ***seafaring***."

Most words dealing with *activities at sea* are adjectives, such as [*maritime*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/maritime), and [*nautical*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/nautical). There may be other *nouns*, but I cannot find them.

Comment: 'Seafaring' is fine for the activities / history, but doesn't work for the hardware. In a bookshop, you usually find 'aviation' and 'maritime' sections.

Comment: There is no such direct counterpart to “aviation”. It could have been “navigation” in its original naval meaning, but it has expanded to cover all travel, by sea, land, or air.